# SQLite3 shows a list of indexes on db:migrate. How do I get rid of this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]

Every time I run a migration, I get this long list of indexing stuff and I have no idea what this is. Did not have this problem in the past. Anyone knows how to get rid of it?

Comment: Where do you get this list? What's your migration code?

Comment: Even with no outstanding migrations, I get this when I run 'rake db:migrate'. Normally if there are no outstanding migrations there will be no output.